# MongoDB updation not working with Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wanted to add new keys to an existing object in a MongoDB docuemnt, I am trying to update the specific abject with update query but I don't see new keys in database.

I have a object like this:

```
{'_id': 'patent_1023', 
'raw': {'id': 'CN-109897889-A',
 'title': 'A kind of LAMP(ring mediated isothermal amplification) product visible detection method', 
'assignee': '北京天恩泽基因科技有限公司', 
'inventor/author': '徐堤',
 'priority_date': '2019-04-17', 
'filing/creation_date': '2019-04-17',
 'publication_date': '2019-06-18', 
'grant_date': None, 
'result_link': 'https://patents.google.com/patent/CN109897889A/en', 'representative_figure_link': None
}, 
'source': 'Google Patent'}
```

I added two new keys in raw and want to update only 'raw' with new keys 'abstract' and 'description'

Here is what I have done.

```
d = client.find_one({'_id': {'$in': ids}})

d['raw'].update(missing_data) # missing_data contain new keys to be added in raw.

here = client.find_one_and_update({'_id': d['_id']}, {'$set': {"raw": d['raw']}})
```

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: Also:  Calling `find_one` with `$in` is puzzling.   This will randomly return the first doc matching the list.

Answer (score 1):

Both `update_one` and `update_many` will work with this:

```py
missing_data = {'abstract':'a book', 'description':'a fun book'};

ids = [ 'patent_1023', 'X'];

rc=db.foo.update_one(
    {'_id': {'$in': ids}},

    # Use pipeline form of update to exploit richer agg framework
    # function like $mergeObjects.  Below we are saying "take the 
    # incoming raw object, overlay the missing_data object on top of
    # it, and then set that back into raw and save":
    [ {'$set': {
        'raw': {'$mergeObjects': [ '$$ROOT.raw', missing_data ] }
      }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: OP was asking for a pymongo answer, which has deprecated `update`.